# Win32 Error# (6): The handle is invalid. when running bpy+flask+EEVEE

Tags: python, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to build my own kind of render server and therefor have a python script that starts `bpy` (headless but still on a PC that has a GPU and multiple displays) and after that serves a `flask` webserver.
The script is really simple:

1. import flask, byp and other libraries needed
2. Load preconfigured blend file (contains some fixed lights and a camera)
3. Import material library
4. Start flask webserver

Now I have exactly one API endpoint that receives the render config as JSON and does the rendering based on the received configuration:

1. Set render engine (`BLENDER_EEVEE` or `CYCLES`)
2. Load Object(s) (STL Files)
3. Position the object(s)
4. (Re)position the camera
5. Set the output file path
6. Render the (`webp`) image(s) and save them
7. Remove objects/meshes after all scenes have been processed

Now, if I send a configuration to the API endpoint that specifies `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = "CYCLES"` as render engine it works as expected and I can send as many requests after another (always waiting until the one running request finished) as I like, always getting the correct output images (tested with 6 images per request).

However, if I send a configuration to the API endpoint that specifies `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = "BLENDER_EEVEE"` as render engine I get the expected output images ONLY after the first request after startup. Every additional request results in multiple `Win32 Error# (6): The handle is invalid.` errors when calling `renderer.render(write_still=True)`. It does not seem to crash because it still shows the blender output on the console and creates images but empty ones.

I am working within Pycharm 23.2.5, with Python 3.10.11 Interpreter (Virtual environment) and have used different bpy versions:

- V 3.6.0 installed from pip
- V 4.1.0 compiled locally according to https://wiki.blender.org/w/index.php?title=Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

Additional info:

- I have also tried to run the rendering part without the flask webserver and its API endpoint and in this scenario both render engines worked as expected after multiple renderings but I would like to keep blender running because the overhead of loading the material library and textures, etc. is bigger than the rendering of my scenes (1 or 2 objects per scenes with a total of less than 10k facets)

Can anyone explain why EEVEE does produce the correct output images but only at the first  request after startup of the webserver and then dont? Why is is working with CYCLES then? What can I do to resolve this error?